# Refactoring Embed message generation for Discord Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, discord.js

I am trying to refactor the code that I am using to generate embeds (user input makes an API call for info, which I display through the embed) with my bot in Discord. I have both a slash command and prefix command version of the code (so that people can either ask the bot with a prefix command or use the slash commands) and I am trying to pull the duplicated code for both those requests into a helper file.

The helper file: (/utils/itemHelper.js)

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { request } = require('undici');
const { ITEM_URL, BASE_URL } = require('./utils');
const { itemAliases } =require('./itemAliases')

async function getItem( itemName ){
    if (itemName in itemAliases){ itemName = itemAliases[itemName] };
    const { body } = await request(ITEM_URL + encodeURIComponent(itemName));
    const { items } = await body.json();

    const [itemAnswer] = items;
    const itemEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(itemAnswer.name)
        .setDescription('Mentor notes will go here.')
        .setImage(BASE_URL + itemAnswer.screenshot)
     
    console.log(itemEmbed);
}

module.exports = { getItem }
```

At this point, the console.log(itemEmbed) gives me what I want:

```
MessageEmbed {
  type: 'rich',
  title: 'Frost Brand',
  description: 'Mentor notes will go here.',
  url: null,
  color: null,
  timestamp: null,
  fields: [],
  thumbnail: null,
  image: { url: 'https://dom5api.illwiki.com/items/14/screenshot' },
  video: null,
  author: null,
  provider: null,
  footer: null
}
```

But by the time I call the function within the file were I create the slash command, I get an error message (which is discord telling me that the embed I want to send is lacking the description field):

```
data.embeds[0].description: This field is required.
```

The slash command file where I call the async function: (/commands/item.js)

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { getItem } = require('../utils/itemHelper')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('item')
        .setDescription('Replies with information about an item')
        .addStringOption(option => option.setName('item_name').setDescription('Enter the name of the item').setRequired(true)),

    async execute(interaction) {
        let itemName = interaction.options.getString('item_name');
        const itemEmbed = getItem( itemName );
        console.log(`itemEmbed:`+ itemEmbed);
        await interaction.reply({ embeds: [itemEmbed] });
    },
};
```

The console.log output is
`itemEmbed:[object Promise]`

My hunch is that I am somehow misunderstanding/misapplying how async functions and promises work (and that the information I need is hidden somewhere inside [object Promise]). I have tried to do 'return itemEmbed' at the end of the helper file, but that didn't solve the issue. I have also considered if I might be missing a param in my async function, but I don't think I need another param, or if I did need one what role it would fill.

Thanks for any/all help in advance!

Comment: `async` functions always return promises, so you'll need to resolve it first. `const itemEmbed = await getItem( itemName )` would work for you.

Comment: Thanks! Adding the 'await' in front of getItem has made it that the console.log now returns 'undefined' for itemEmbed. I am not sure I understand what you meant under resolving the promise. Adding a Promise.resolve()?

Comment: `await` already resolves it. Another problem is you use `console.log(itemEmbed)` instead of `return itemEmbed`, so it returns `undefined`

Comment: That solved the issue. I feel so silly for forgetting to do a return at the end of my funciton. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `getItem` function, there's two problems:

1. You made it [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). When a function is asynchronous, it is considered as a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Promises) that you have to use the [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) keyword on `await getItem(..)` So that it will wait for the fetch to finish to finally continue executing your code.
2. You don't [`return`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return) anything on your function. You log the embed in your console.
   Try using it like so :

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const { request } = require('undici');
const { ITEM_URL, BASE_URL } = require('./utils');
const { itemAliases } =require('./itemAliases')

function getItem( itemName ){
    if (itemName in itemAliases){ itemName = itemAliases[itemName] };
    const { body } = await request(ITEM_URL + encodeURIComponent(itemName));
    const { items } = await body.json();

    const [itemAnswer] = items;
    const itemEmbed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(itemAnswer.name)
        .setDescription('Mentor notes will go here.')
        .setImage(BASE_URL + itemAnswer.screenshot)
    return itemEmbed
}

module.exports = { getItem }
```

```js
        const itemEmbed = await getItem(itemName);
```

Comment: Ah, I did miss/forget to return the itemEmbed at the end of my helper file. I used it an async function because I have to 'await's - to request the information from the API and then put that into a body that I can use later on.
`const { body } = await request(ITEM_URL + encodeURIComponent(itemName));
 const { items } = await body.json();`

Comment: @ToldiReloaded Oh my bad didn't see that, here I fixed it

Comment: Thanks - I kept it as an async function due to the two 'await's that I am using to make sure I get the info before sending the embed, but I did totally forget to return itemEmbed. Once I 'returned' it at the end of the async function, everything started working like it should. Thanks!